# Fails to pass column into SQL user function

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SELECT query uses a searched CASE expression. In that CASE, I call a user function. I want to pass into that user function a value from the SELECT.

We have multiple SQL Servers. On one server, this SQL fails, but runs fine on other servers.

The theory is a compatibility issue between the servers. The working servers have `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` of 90. The failing server is 80.

Is this a compatibility error?

Error message:

> Line 16: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1:
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'UT'.

SQL code (faking the tables for SO):

```
CREATE FUNCTION uf_TestFunction_table
(@Number Int)
RETURNS TABLE
    RETURN (SELECT UserId FROM [dbo].[User] WHERE [UserID] = @Number)
GO

SELECT TOP 1
UT.UserID, 
UT.Deleted,
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[uf_TestFunction_table]([UT].[UserID])) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FOO
FROM [dbo].[User] UT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this link, Functions which returns TABLE should be used as table (i.e. used in join or after  from clause).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167399/Using-Table-Valued-Functions-in-SQL-Server

your code should be like following, I haven't executed this statements, just modified & pasted.

```
SELECT TOP 1
UT.UserID, 
UT.Deleted,
CASE WHEN fun.UserId IS not null  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FOO
FROM [dbo].[User] UT
left join [dbo].[uf_TestFunction_table]([UT].[UserID]) as fun on fun.UserId =UT.UserID
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use table-valued function in select clause, insted use cross apply in your query which will work like inner joint.

from the result use the case for your desired output...